# Rails session variable doesn't get set until page reload

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, session, devise, session-variables

I have a session variable that I want to set when a user hits the devise login page. Unfortunately it doesn't take effect after I get redirected. Instead, I have to refresh the page and then I see the new variable.

I have tried a few things:

First I tried just setting the session variable
`session[:theme] = theme`

Then I tried deleting the old key and setting a new key:

```
case theme
  when 'theme1'
    session.delete(:theme2)
    session[:theme1] = true
  else
    session.delete(:theme1)
    session[:theme2] = true
  end
```

Both of these require a page refresh after I am redirected to the login form. My server logs are showing that the session variable is being picked up but the browser just doesn't seem to want to change it until I reload.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: So you have solution for this yet?

Answer (score 0):

You need to override Devise' `SessionsController.new` action to accomplish this.  Make sure you have something like this defined in `config/routes.rb`:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  ...
  devise_for :users, controllers: {sessions: 'sessions'}
  ...
end
```

And then in `app/controllers/sessions_controller.rb`:

```
class SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController
  def new
    super do |resource|
      session[:my_session_variable] = 'hello world'
    end
  end
end
```